# Can anyone identify this?

Tags: species-identification

Found on Cape Cod MA near a fresh water pond with a muddy bottom. Strange looking creature with a suction cup single "foot" with a mouth opening on opposite end, no limbs, mouth ridges inside mouth, spiral rings of tissue up entire body. Any idea what it is? I thought it might be a tunicate of some kind but I can't find a match anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is a artificial fishing lure.specifically a soft worm T-tail, there are hundreds of variations. 
[image]

Comment: Really, just wow on this one.

Comment: This may be a mimic but what I have is NOT plastic,

Comment: Okay, now we may BOTH be right. This thing I have is not plastic but I finally cut in to it an VIOLA! It is a colony of mud worms that probably took up residence in one and the plastic is long gone, the outside is a mud shell, the inside is a mess of worms...............

Comment: Not all lures are plastic many are latex